# Something is going wrong during suspend and battery is dying

Tags: suspend, dell, power-management, 22.04, battery

I have a Dell XPS 13 9380 with 22.04 installed.

Recently, sometimes (but only sometimes) when suspending, the computer appears to suspend correctly (i.e., the screen shuts off) but after a few hours the battery is nearly depleted.

Where should I be looking in the logs to figure out what is happening?

Comment: Suspend uses some power to keep the RAM turned on. If you suspend your laptop and forget about it, the battery will eventually get to 0. First, make sure that is not the case. Test if the laptop is really suspending. Start watching a movie (one you have watched before) and suspend for 30 minutes. When you wake the laptop, does the movie start where you left off?

Comment: Check dmesg, /var/log/syslog, /var/log/kernlog, check the bios doesn't have S3 disabled,

Comment: Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28097/how-to-debug-a-suspend-problem#29090